# error history view_galleriffic

Tags: views, theming, javascript

I'm using [Views Galleriffic](http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery) (6.x-1.x-dev) and [Node Gallery](http://drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module and there is an error.

In the Firebug console, my error is shown as:

```
$("a[rel='history']").live is not a function in line 93 $("a[rel='history']").live('click', function(e) in file view_galleriffic.js
```

I uploaded jquery.history.js in module view_galleriffic/js/...
my website link :http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/fa/galleriffic/95
help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method wasn't added to jQuery until v1.3. Your site is currently using the standard jQuery library included in Drupal 6, v1.2.6.

To fix this all you need to do is download and install the [jQuery Update](http://drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module. That will upgrade your site's jQuery library to v1.3.2 and you should stop getting the errors.

Comment: i installed jquery update 6.x-1.x-dev.plz help more thanks a lot

Comment: Have a look at the source code for the site, it's currently including http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/misc/jquery.js?l` which is a file containing jQuery version 1.2.6. So it looks like jQuery update isn't installed or isn't working. Try downloading and enabling the stable release, not the dev.

Comment: download http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3/jquery.min.js and replace /misc/jquery.js in localhost but not working

Comment: You haven't replaced the right file, it's still version 1.2.6: http://demo.dolphin-sch.ir/nagara/misc/jquery.js?l. Check the comments at the top, it contains the version number. Maybe you haven't committed/uploaded the file to the live site? I should mention that it's really not a good idea to just overwrite the existing jQuery file; the JS on some of your admin pages will stop working. The jQuery Update module fixes this problem, and I'm positive it's not installed on your site (at least on the one at the URL you've posted).